# Block a thread - spin-lock replacement

Tags: java, lock-free

I have implemented several lock-free algorithms to maximise throughput but have always baulked when performing a spin-lock. I can usually convince myself that this is the only way but it still nags at me that a spin-lock is a terribly bad idea.

I recently came across a [FIFOMutex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html) code fragment and thought perhaps that would be a solution. I have hacked it around a bit because I don't want mine to consume interrupt exceptions but essentially it looks like this:

```
/**
 * Queue of blocked writers.
 */
private static class BlockedQueue {
  // Everyone who is waiting.
  private final Queue<Thread> waiting = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
  // Ensure only one thread unlocks at a time.
  private final AtomicBoolean lock = new AtomicBoolean(false);

  public void sleep() {
    Thread me = Thread.currentThread();
    // Put me in the queue.
    waiting.add(me);
    try {
      do {
        // Park until I am head of the queue and I hold the lock
        LockSupport.park(this);
        /*
         * If I am not at the head of the queue - go back to sleep.
         *
         * If I am at the head of the queue - grab the lock and get out of the loop.
         *
         * If I was at the head and I couldn't get the lock - go back to sleep -
         * someone else is still in the process of exiting.
         */
      } while (!(waiting.peek() == me && lock.compareAndSet(false, true)));
    } finally {
      // Take me from the queue - it must be me because I locked everyone else out.
      waiting.remove();
      // Done with the lock.
      lock.set(false);
    }
  }

  public void wakeup() {
    // Wake the first in the queue ... unpark does nothing with a null parameter.
    LockSupport.unpark(waiting.peek());
  }
}
// Use this to block for a while.
private final BlockedQueue block = new BlockedQueue();

/**
 * Wait for a time when it is likely that a free slot is available.
 */
private void waitForFree() {
  // Still full?
  while (isFull()) {
    // Park me 'till something is removed.
    block.sleep();
  }
}

/**
 * A slot has been freed up. If anyone is waiting, let the next one know.
 */
private void signalFree() {
  block.wakeup();
}
```

See how I can now call `block.sleep()` in what used to be a spin-lock around `while(isFull())`.

What I like most about this is that the `wakeup` method is truly simple and that it will only wake up the thread that has been waiting longest.

I have some questions though:

1. Will this do what I want it to do - i.e. handle multiple threads waiting for a resource without consuming unnecessary CPU.
2. Is the `while ((removed = waiting.remove()) != me)` necessary? Logic suggests that the head of the queue at that point **must** be me but is there a scenario where it may not be?

Comment: Note - I have tinkered with it a bit since first post so if you have taken a copy to test, please recopy.

Comment: also I am adding an answer ... just takes some time.

Comment: Tweaked again - please take a new copy.

Comment: I think the problem with the current/latest revision is that the first thread in to your system will need a wakeup() to work

Comment: @rolfl - that was the intent because of `private void waitForFree() { while (isFull()) { block.sleep(); } }`. It will **only** sleep if the queue was full at one point. Note that `LockSupport.unpark` *... Otherwise, its next call to park is guaranteed not to block.*. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Just to be clear, do you need the order in which the threads 'queue' to be 'fair'? (i.e. it has to be FIFO?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting a second answer to keep things clean.

I think I missed one of the important concepts in your use-case, that you are 'gating' the access to the resource from the resource-side of things, not the thread side of things....

If I were to suggest the following code, I think it would add to this 'conversation':

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;


public class ResourceWaitQueue {

    private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true); // use a FIFO lock.
    private final Condition goodtogo = lock.newCondition();
    private int releasecount = 0; // how many threads should be released.

    public final void await() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (releasecount == 0) {
                goodtogo.await();
            }
            // releasecount > 0 and we were signalled.
            if (--releasecount > 0) {
                // reduce the releasdecount, but there's still another
                // thread that should be released.
                goodtogo.signal();
                // when that other thread releases, if there's still more
                // to be released, it can do that for us.
            };
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public final void release() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            // indicate there is work to do
            releasecount++;
            // signal the condition is true.... (only signal, not signalAll())
            goodtogo.signal();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }


}
```

The above will queue threads up, using the 'fair' (FIFO) nature of the Re-Entrant Lock (or you can use the faster 'unfair' version too). It uses the lock to queue up threads, and it will release as many threads as times you call `release`.

Comment: You are right - I should have gone for a `Condition` in the first place and this is certainly the correct approach. It just seems strange to write a lock-free high-performace mechanism and then make use of locks and blocks when really all I want is a reliable and lightweight `Thread.yield()`.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon: I may have missed something but what about a fair Semaphore? Wouldn't it good?

Answer (score 2):

I believe there's race conditions in your code, Specifically, if you call `wakeup()` asymettrically (more times than you call `sleep()`) then you run the risk of a few things:

1. you could have multiple running threads (i.e. there's not just one thread using the resource)
2. you may possibly trigger a condition where calling wakeup() twice, very fast, will cause the **same** thread to be unparked (i.e. `waiting.peek()` in `wakeup()`) will return the same value twice....).
3. it is possible that the queue does not contain a value when the wakeup is called because the 'active' thread is in the process of looking for itself (and removing other content from the queue) as it goes.

I have tried to find a way to make it work to my satisfaction below, but, frankly, I don't think it is possible without changing the code so much it is no longer 'yours'.

I think the reality is that a secure mechanism for this will necessarily rely on having a lock that contains both the unpark and the queue management.... at which point, using the park/unpark is no longer the right tool, so it defeats this process...

Feel free to read through what I was about to write, but, I am essentially abandoning it....

---

DISREGARD BELOW HERE

Right, you'll have to work with me on this one.... (it takes multiple 'heads' to work around 'threads'....)...

First, let me restate the problem I think you are trying to solve:

- you have a resource that only one thread can access at a time
- you want the 'waiting' threads to be queued (essentially in FIFO order) until the resource is available.
- you want the waiting threads to be (b)locked rather than spinning.

You want the 'outside' code to look something like (this code will be in the resource-using threads):

```
try {
    blockedqueue.sleep(); // wait for my turn to use the resource
    doSomethingWith(resource);
} finally {
    blockedqueue.wakeup(); // indicate that another thread can use the resource.
}
```

I see that you start the BlockedQueue off in an 'unblocked' state, so the first thread in will immediately return. Only 'subsequent' threads will wait.

There is a gap in your logic though.... (hate to be the bearer of bad news....)...

It is possible for the queue to be empty when `wakeup()` is called **even though there are blocked threads**. This is because you may be removing() items in your loop at the same time as when the wake-up is called.

Also, I think that you should be more precise about what threads can re-awaken the queue. I like the try-finally concept which will assure that the same thread that calls `sleep()` will also call `wakeup()`.

Consider the following alteration. Instead of using an AtomicBoolean to lock the thread, use an AtomicReference  (and I have renamed it to 'active' instead of 'lock'....

```
public void wakeup() {
    // Unlock.
    if (active.compareAndSet(this, null)) {
        // Wake the first in the queue (and remove it too) ... unpark does nothing with a null parameter.
        LockSupport.unpark(waiting.poll());
    } else {
        throw new IllegalMonitorStateException("Cannot unlock a thread unless you are the owner of the lock");
    }
}
```

This will prevent spurious wake-ups, but if you have asymmetrical code (more `wakeup()` than `sleep()`) you will get exceptions (I think that's a good thing).

In your `sleep()` method you can also gain some efficiency by not using the queue at all if you're the only active thread...

```
public void sleep() {
    final Thread me = Thread.currentThread();
    if (blocked.compareAndSet(null, me) {
        // nothing is waiting, next threads will, but we can just keep going
        // there is a slight possibility that we can 'jump the queue'
        // if sleep() is called at **just** the right time...
        return;
    }

    // here we know that some other thread is active....
    // Put me in the queue.
    waiting.add(me);
    try {
        // Block while not first in queue or we're blocked
        // wait till we are at the front of the queue and we are also
        // not blocked by anything. If we are blocked, then park.
        // If not, we immediately block the next front-of-queue as well.
        while (waiting.peek() != me || !blocked.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            LockSupport.park(this);
        }
    } finally {
       // Take me from the queue.
       Thread removed;
       while ((removed = waiting.remove()) != me) {
           // Put it back! It wasn't me!
           waiting.add(removed);
       }
    }
}
```

I think you may have a problem with initial state, and spurious wake-ups.... Consider the following

You have multiple instances of a Runnable (`ta` and `tb` for thread A and thread B), each of them does `blockingqueue.sleep()`. The expectation is that they will be woken up in turn when the queue's `wakup()` method is called (wake up both `ta` and `tb` by calling `wakeup()` twice).

So, both threads are asleep, the queue contains `[ta, tb]` and the atomic boolean `blocked` is false (the

Comment: Thanks for the attention. I think I picked up on your point about the initial condition problem and tweaked the code to deal with that - see the `do { ... } while ...` rather than the `while ... {...}`. Still thinking about your other points ...

Comment: I know my answer is a mess... and any threading problem is hard to describe. If you have any questions, feel free to discuss.

Comment: Of your points 1, 2 and 3 - I think the `while ((removed = ...` loop can be replaced completely by just `waiting.remove()` like in the original code because the logic dictates that the head of the queue **must** be `me` at this point. If that is the case then I suspect your concerns are unfounded. I think there **is** an issue in that area but I cannot define it at this time and I am still not certain you are wrong.

Comment: I've tweaked it again and added some more comments - mostly to clarify my own thoughts. It seems to still work but I haven't managed to work out an effective test for it yet.